# Hangman jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have created a hangman based on a jQuery code that I found online. I understand how the code works and it works perfectly if I want to use only one word. I want to use game with  multiple words, so I have created a function, in order to do so.
unfortunately, it doesn't work with the function.

This is the function that I have created:

```
 function hangman(var word)
        {
            var alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $.each(alpha.split(''), function(i, val){
            $('#alpha').append($('<span class="guess">' + val + '</span>'));
            });
            $.each(word.split(''), function(i, val){
            $('#word').append($('<span class="letter" letter="' + val +'">_</span>'));
            });
            $('.guess').click(function(){
            var count = $('#word [letter='+$(this).text()+']').each(function(){ $(this).text($(this).attr('letter'));}).length;
            $(this).removeClass('guess').css('color' , (count > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')).unbind('click');
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#BUT').click(function() {
            hangman('DOG');
                });
            });
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div id="hangman-jquery">
    <div id="word"></div>
    <div id="alpha"></div>
</div>
<button id= "BUT" ></button>
```

as I said, it doesn't work. Do you know the solution by any chance?

Comment: *How* doesn't it work?  What indication do you have that it's failing?  Explain the expected behavior vs. the observed behavior.  When you debug the code, at what point do these behaviors diverge?  What are the relevant runtime values at that time?  "It doesn't work" isn't useful information.

Comment: To be able to write javascript/jquery you need the firebug console. It does not work is the most ambiguous error possible:). Explain us!

Comment: well you could make array of list of characters which can be chosen and then delete it if something is already chosen ?

Comment: You also do realize, it invalidates the id tag if you put a space before it and the equal sign, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function hangman(var word)
//                ^try removing 'var'
```

seems to work then in some way: http://jsfiddle.net/BdkTC/